# C# conditional using and default parameter

Tags: c#

Lets assume, we have an operation based on some file, connection, or other resource.

We need a method, which can be run with provided resource, or - if not provided - creates own:

```
string Foo(Resource parameter = null)
{
    if (parameter == null)
    {
        using (var res = new Resource)
        {
            res.Something();
               /*......*/
               /*......*/
               /*......*/
            return /*..........*/
        }
    }
    else 
    {
            parameter.Something();
               /*......*/
               /*......*/
               /*......*/
            return /*..........*/
    }
 }
```

}

It works, but this is really ugly for me.
Is it a way to write it in more compact and "nice" way?

I cannot use:

```
string Foo(Resource parameter = null)
{
    using (var res = parameter ?? new Resource())
    {
        res.Something();
           /*......*/
           /*......*/
           /*......*/
        return /*..........*/
    }
}
```

as it disposes my original Resource if passed as parameter.

PS. What is proper tag for this question? #coding-style is marked as "do not use".

Comment: This question belongs in Code Review SE : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One simple approach would be to just recurse if `parameter` is null:

```cs
string Foo(Resource parameter = null)
{
    if (parameter == null)
    {
        using (var res = new Resource())
        {
            return Foo(res);   
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        parameter.Something();
        ...
        return ...;
    }
}
```

You'll only recurse once, so you don't need to worry about unbounded stacks etc.

Comment: Great! In fact, you don't even need "else" nor any braces!

Comment: @JakubSzułakiewicz: There are lots of times where braces aren't *required* - but they're almost always a good idea anyway. (Whether you use the `else` or not is a matter of personal taste.)

Answer (score 5):

I would go with 2 separate methods. The one will contain all the logic - it will be clear and easy to maintain.

```
string Foo(Resource parameter)
{
     parameter.Something();
     /...../
     return /...../;
}

string Foo()
{
     using (var res = new Resource)
     {
         return Foo(res);
     }
}
```

This case also useful if you want to use injected parameter for testing purpose only. Looking for usages of parameterless method will lead to actual implementation, the other one will lead you directly to test cases.

Answer (score 3):

I'd go for a local function:

```
string Foo(Resource parameter = null)
{
    if (parameter != null)
    {
        return DoSomething(parameter);
    }

    using (var resource = new Resource())
    {
        return DoSomething(resource);
    }

    string DoSomething(Resource res)
    {
        res.Something();
        /...../
        return /...../
    }
}
```

(In C# 8, you can make that a `static` local function).

If `parameter` can only be `null` when it's not provided (i.e. someone would never call `Foo(null)`), then you can use good old method overloading:

```
string Foo(Resource resource)
{
    resource.Something();
    /...../
    return /...../
}

string Foo()
{
    using (var res = new Resource())
    {
        return Foo(res);
    }
}
```

Comment: That was my initial thought as well. Then I figured this was equivalent to just calling the same method recursively in the "parameter is null" case.

Comment: On the else you should use `parameter` as parameter, not `res`. I'd also remove the else statement and just leave `return DoSomething(parameter);`

Comment: @JonSkeet Yep, that's fair. That's a bit cleaner; the downside is it might take someone who's not used to that pattern a few more milliseconds to parse. Upvoted yours, I'll leave mine as an alternative.

Comment: @ALFA D'oh, thanks. Personally I prefer balancing ifs and elses, but that's a background in medical software speaking. Also inverted the `if` to reduce the indentation by a level.

Answer (score -1):

Checkout this.

```
string Foo(Resource parameter = null)
        {
            if (parameter != null)
            {
                parameter.Something();
                return;
            }
            using (var res = new Resource())
            {
                return Foo(res);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This falls under the "I cannot use ... as it disposes my original Resource if passed as parameter." part of the question

Comment: This is now the same as Jon Skeet's answer (but with the if/else inverted)